# React: Getting absolute URLs with <StaticRouter /> and <Link to="/path/to/page" />

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to turn render some HTML for an email using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the paths in a `<Link />` to resolve to absolute URLs.

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location="http://www.test.com" context={context}>
      <Provider store={store}>{content}</Provider>
    </StaticRouter>,
  );
```

I would assume that if in my `<App>` I had a `<Link to="/path/xyz" />` that that would result in: `<a href="http://www.test.com/path/xy">`, but it's not.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a normal `<a href="">` ? Links are meant for internal navigation. Check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/985pl2/reactrouter_href_link_to_external_url_with_state/) and [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147).

Comment: I'm trying to reuse the same components for rendering an email and for rendering in the web app.